# Two dimensional materials in quantum computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science, quantum-computer

There is a concept of [topological quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_computer) using quasiparticles called [anyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon) to physically implement quantum gates. These gates use effects in 2D space which is *simulated* by some 3D structures:

> Their approach is based on topological Majorana states, which occur at edges of a topological superconducting chain or at interfaces between such chains.

**My question is whether [two dimensional materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_materials) are used (or proposed to be used) for construction of the topological quantum computer.**

According to [this answer on Quantum computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11399/topological-quantum-computer-and-two-dimensional-materials) graphene is not used, **but what about other 2D materials?**

Comment: This question would fit well on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)